# ubuntu - looking for IDE compiler to build and run a .c source file without creating a project

Tags: c, compiler-construction, ide, codeblocks

I have ubuntu 12.04 and KDE.

I already know Code::BLocks that does the job, but I have a problem with it: any version of it (12.11 or 10.05) I use doesn't close when I click the close button and if i try to make any change to editor setting it's not saved. So I'm looking for a IDE compiler for c programs that does the same job with c source file. I need it for university, my teacher uses Dev-C++ for windows but I have ubuntu and I need something similar to open a .c source and build and run it as faster as I can. If there are no ide like codeblocks maybe something like eclipse, netbeans, codelite etc... have a plugin to build a .c source without making a project I don't know. Please help

Thanks

Comment: If all you have is a single file or two then just compile it with the command line.

Comment: I found anjuta 3.4 on repository. I downloaded the plugins and now i can compile a .c source file BUT I can't run it because when I run it a "program parameters" windows opens in which I can insert aguments, program, environment variables, execute in terminal etc... and I don't know what to do. Any help?

Answer (score 2):

I usually do that by writing the C code with `gedit` and then I compile it with `gcc` always through command-line. I don't know if that's exactly what you were looking for. You may prefer a graphical interface, but I find myself comfortable working that way.

To quickly compile and run a code, you would write something like this:

```
me@mybox:~# gcc -o test test.c
me@mybox:~# ./test
```

Comment: thanks, I prefer graphical interface. I know about those commands, but i'd like something faster than writing every time gcc commands

Comment: http://www.codelite.org/ could be what you're looking for.

Comment: ok but is it possible to compile and run without making project?

Answer (score 0):

If your .c file is called `test` you can also try the following from the command line:

`$ make test`

It will produce an executable for you called `test` that you can run in the following way:

`$ ./test`